# Change of variable conflict

Tags: logarithms, change-of-variable

I was trying to solve a problem. Due to solve, I tried to use change a variable but I saw, I got a conflict after do it.

Let's assume $y=1+n+n^2$ and lets try to change n variable with $n^k=\log(m^k)$

$y=\log(1\cdot m^0)+\log(m)+\log(m^2)=0+3⋅\log(m)$

If we try to go back, $\log(m)=n$

$y=3⋅n$

And as you see, the original equation $y=1+n+n^2$ is not equal to $y=3⋅n$ If we calculate two equation for $2$, equation one is $7$ equation two is $6$.

What is the problem ? We always do it for integral or some other problems.

Thanks.

Comment: In general $\log m \neq n$.

Comment: "We always do it": no, not like that.

Comment: "If we try to go back, log(m)=n": if you have log(m)=n, then you have (log(m))^2=n^2 and not log(m^2) = n^2

Comment: $$y=1+e^{m^k/k}+e^{2m^k/k}.$$

Comment: @miracle173 but my definition is not $n^k = ((log(m))^k$ I want to define $n^k = log(m^k)$ can't we find a m value that provide this equation ?

Comment: @BobbyLaspy, your equation is valid for $log(n) = m$ I guess.

Comment: @Wtow if you define $n^k = \log(m^k)$ (use a backslash before log), then $n$ is not $\log m$. But we have $n = \sqrt[k]{\log m^k}$. But I think that is not very useful.

Comment: @miracle173 can't we say if $k = 1$, $n = \log(m)$ ?

Comment: @Wtow If you define $n^k = \log(m^k)$, you do this for a fixed $k$.  $n$ and $m$ are the variables. So if you say $k=1$, then $n = \log(m)$ but $n^2=(n = \log(m))^2$. If you say $k=2$, then $n^2 = \log(m^2)$ but $n = \sqrt[k]{\log m^k}$. But as BobbyLaspy wrote in his answer, you cannot have $n^k=\log(m^k)$ for several values of $k$ simultaneously. Compare to other substitutions that you made in the past.

Comment: @miracle173 I understand now, thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$n^k=\log(m^k)$$ cannot hold for several values of $k$ simultaneously.

For instance,

$$n=\log(m)$$ does not imply

$$n^2=\log(m^2)$$

because that would mean
$$n^2=\log(m^2)=2\log(m)=2n.$$

Comment: So, what is the rule to change of variable if we can not do it as arbitary

Comment: @Wtow: $n^k=\log(m^k)$ is a valid change of variable (though I have never needed that). The way you use it is wrong.

Comment: What is correct usage way ?